# Linked list with struct, recursive data structure with UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift, struct, linked-list, swift2, recursive-datastructures

I tried to create a linked list with `struct` (I know it can be done with `enum`s or `class`es), and here is my attempt:

```
struct LinkedListStruct<T> {

    let head: T
    var tail: UnsafeMutablePointer<LinkedListStruct<T>>
}
```

it compiles fine, but when I try to use it in a very simple way:

```
let list = LinkedListStruct(head: 1, tail: nil)

print("End")
```

`"End"` will never be printed out to the console. At the debug navigator view, the cpu usage is at 0% and the memory is not increasing, so I assume that it is not due to recursion. What's wrong with this implementation?

Comment: It is probably an error of the Swift compiler. At least some error message should be reported either by the compiler or by the run-time system. Report the bug at [https://bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: @Renzo you are probably right, I will report it

Comment: Do you need to use `UnsafeMutablePointer`? Since a wrapper class wouldn't be as unsafe.

Comment: @Qbyte no, I don't need to use it, It was just an experiment if this is possible or not.